# Populating a matrix (or a DF or a DT) with a loop from a folder containing txt files

Tags: r, loops, text, directory

I wrote my first code in R for treating some spectra [basically .txt files with a Xcol (wavelength) and Ycol (intensity)].

The code works for single files, provided *I write* the file name in the code. Here the code working for the first file HKU47_PSG_1_LW_0.txt.

```
  setwd("C:/Users/dd16722/R/Raman/Data")

# import Spectra
PSG1_LW<-read.table("HKU47_PSG_1_LW_0.txt")
colnames(PSG1_LW)[colnames(PSG1_LW)=="V2"] <- "PSG1_LW"
PSG2_LW<-read.table("HKU47_PSG_2_LW_all_0.txt")
colnames(PSG2_LW)[colnames(PSG2_LW)=="V2"] <- "PSG2_LW"

#Plot 2 spectra and define the Y range
plot(PSG1_LW$V1, PSG1_LW$PSG1_LW, type="l",xaxs="i", yaxs="i", main="Raman spectra", xlab="Raman shift (cm-1)", ylab="Intensity", ylim=range(PSG1_LW,PSG2_LW))
lines(PSG2_LW$V1, PSG2_LW$PSG2_LW, col=("red"), yaxs="i")

# Temperature-excitation line correction
laser = 532

PSG1_LW_corr <- PSG1_LW$PSG1_LW*((10^7/laser)^3*(1-exp(-6.62607*10^(-34)*29979245800*PSG1_LW$V1/(1.3806488*10^(-23)*293.15)))*PSG1_LW$V1/((10^7/laser)-PSG1_LW$V1)^4)

PSG1_Raw_Corr <-cbind (PSG1_LW,PSG1_LW_corr)
lines(PSG1_LW$V1, PSG1_LW_corr, col="red")
plot(PSG1_LW$V1, PSG1_Raw_Corr$PSG1_LW_corr, type="l",xaxs="i", yaxs="i", xlab="Raman shift (cm-1)", ylab="Intensity")
```

Now, it's time for another little step forward. In the folder, there are many spectra (in the code above I reported the second one: HKU47_PSG_2_LW_all_0.txt) having again 2 columns, same length of the first file. I suppose I should merge all the files in a matrix (or DF or DT).
Probably I need a loop as I need a code able to check automatically the number of files contained in the folder and ultimately to create an object with several columns (i.e. the double of the number of the files).

So I started like this:

```
listLW <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "LW")
numLW <- as.integer(length(listLW))
```

numLW represents the number of iterations I need to set. The question is: how can I populate a matrix (or DF or DT) in order to have in the first 2 columns the first txt file in my folder, then the second file in the 3rd and 4th columns etc? Considering that I need to perform some other operations as I showed above in the code.

I have been reading about loop in R since yestarday but actually could not find the best and easy solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
# Load data.table library
require(data.table)

# Import the first file
DT_final <- fread(file = listLW[1])

# Loop over the rest of the files and use cbind to merge them into 1 DT
for(file in setdiff(listLW, listLW[1])) {
  DT_temp <- fread(file)
  DT_final <- cbind(DT_final, DT_temp)
}
```

Comment: Great Stefan, it works perfectly! Short and concise.

Comment: Here my attempt to rename the columns of the DT created. It is problably too complicated, what do you think?

`namesLW <- c(1:(2*numLW))
for(i in 1:(numLW*2)) {
  if (i %% 2) {namesLW[i]="Raman shift (cm-1)"
  }
  else {namesLW[i]= (listLW[i/2])
  }
}
names(DT_final) <- c(namesLW)`

Comment: You don't need an additional loop. Just add `setnames(DT_temp, c("Raman shift (cm-1)", file))` after the `DT_temp` assignment and `setnames(DT_final, c("Raman shift (cm-1)", listLW[1]))` after the import of the first file

Comment: Great Stefan. Now I did some operations for each column and I would like to plot, in 1 plot, 1st vs 2nd, 3rd vs 4th, 5th vs 6th etc columns. I tried with `plot(DT_final_LW[,1], DT_final_LW[,2])` just to test if I can plot the first 2 columns but did not work. I looked at _tableplot_ function but I cannot see how to define which columns I want to plot. Suggestions?

Comment: `DT_final_LW[,1]` will return a DT object. Try to convert it to a vector before plotting: `plot(unlist(DT_final_LW[,1]), unlist(DT_final_LW[,2]))`

Comment: Thanks, it works and I learned something else. I am trying to loop over the rest of files. I have something like this: `for(i in 1:(numLW*2)) {
  lines(unlist(DT_final_LW[,i]), unlist(DT_final_LW[,(i+1)]))
}`. I know that It is wrong in principle because I want to plot 1st vs 2nd, 3rd vs 4th, 5th vs 6th etc but I tried to anyway to seeing if it works. It does not. Where am I wrong?

Comment: For `i = numLW*2`, the value of `DT_final_LW[,(i+1)]` is not well defined. Try to adjust the upper bound to `numLW*2 - 1`

Comment: Actually, the problem is that I can plot something like this `lines(unlist(DT_final_LW[,3]), unlist(DT_final_LW[,4]))` but as soon as I change the argument with letters or strings like `lines(unlist(DT_final_LW[,(2*i-1)]), unlist(DT_final_LW[,2*i]))` or `lines(unlist(DT_final_LW[,a]), unlist(DT_final_LW[,b]))` does not work. Am I allowed to write there only numbers?

Comment: One way to access a column of a data.table `DT` by its position `i` is `DT[[i]]`. Hence `lines(DT_final_LW[[2*i-1]], DT_final_LW[[2*i]])`. `Unlist` is not longer required as the result is already a vector